# How to make regex of 0-272

Tags: regex

I want to make regex from 0-272. I made this but its not working properly.

```
^([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-2])$
```

This accept 270,272,102 but not accept 103 and 104. How can i make it?

Comment: Could you please clarify what strings the regex is **supposed** to accept?

Comment: 0 to 272 will accept

Comment: Range between 0 to 272

Comment: Oh, now I understand the dash :-) Why even use a regex? Just convert it to numeric and perform a range check.

Comment: Actually, i can do this but i am leaning regex. That's why i am doing this with regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, I don't think this is a good usecase for a regex. But if that's the requirement it could be done. Let's break it up to usecaes:

- Any 1 digit number
- Any 2 digit number
- Any three digit number with a 1 hundreds digits
- Any three digit number with a 2 hundreds digits and a tens digit of 0-6
- Any three digit number with a 2 hundreds digits, a tens digit of 7 and a ones digit of 0-2:

So if we express this as a regex:

```
^([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-6][0-9]|27[0-2])$
```

Comment: what a way you have explained. I love this. The way in which you break the problem.Its appreciable. Thanks buddy.

Comment: I'd personally use quantifiers to avoid repetition and combine the first two cases as `^([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-6][0-9]|27[0-2])$`.  Both yours and mine allow a two digit number with a leading 0 (08 for instance).  The OP hasn't specified if this is ok or not.

Answer (score 1):

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/dX6cS4/1)

```
^(\d|\d\d|[01][0-9][0-9]|2[0-6][0-9]|27[0-2])$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/uMagYAstDRaY-N06)

### Description

```
^ assert position at start of a line
1st Capturing group (\d|\d\d|[01][0-9][0-9]|2[0-6][0-9]|27[0-2])
    1st Alternative: \d
        \d match a digit [0-9]
    2nd Alternative: \d\d
        \d match a digit [0-9]
        \d match a digit [0-9]
    3rd Alternative: [01][0-9][0-9]
        [01] match a single character present in the list below
            01 a single character in the list 01 literally
        [0-9] match a single character present in the list below
            0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
        [0-9] match a single character present in the list below
            0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
    4th Alternative: 2[0-6][0-9]
        2 matches the character 2 literally
        [0-6] match a single character present in the list below
            0-6 a single character in the range between 0 and 6
        [0-9] match a single character present in the list below
            0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
    5th Alternative: 27[0-2]
        27 matches the characters 27 literally
        [0-2] match a single character present in the list below
            0-2 a single character in the range between 0 and 2
$ assert position at end of a line
```